# Synchronize dynamic audio and code in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, synchronization, haxe

I'm currently programming a little game which involved that a **dynamically created music** is playing, and on a specific tone, a function is called to update the game.

I have no problem with dynamically creating music, either using `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA` or the wonderful **[standingwave2](http://code.google.com/p/standingwave/)** lib, but I can't find out how to synchronize sound with code.

I know the "sync" note play every X ms (let's say 500), so I've tried to start a timer which ticks every 500ms right after starting the sound, but it gets eventually out of sync. I'm not sure if the timer isn't good enough to follow the path

I know there's a way to put music on Adobe IDE Frames, play sound as "stream" and then put some code on each frame so I can know where it's called, but I can't dynamically create music that way.

So, does anyone knows a way to synchronize my function call with the sound I'm creating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this depends on when and how does the music generation takes place. If you are generating that music prior to running the game, then you can yield time offset list in that music when the particular tone is generated into that music, then you make a sorted array out of those values, then when the music is actively started, you take flash.utils.getTimer() value and store it as your base time. After this, each frame you check if current getTimer() value is greater than current array position, and if so, the function you want is called, and you advance one position in the array, to be ready for the next pre-set occurrence of your desired tone.

If, on the other hand, you generate music on the fly, a couple of frames length each, then you have to lock getTimer() value at the start of the game and (supposedly) music generation, so that each pair of values you put into sampleData are exactly 1/44100 second of music played. You then count those pairs (on the fly, of course) until it'll be time to insert your desired tone into the generated music, then you'll have an offset from sound start. Convert it to milliseconds, then check each frame if current getTimer() minus stored tick count is greater or equal to discovered offset, and if true, call the function.

Comment: This is what I would start with.  It's matching *real* time to *audio* time to *frames*; it's not **two** variables that you are trying to compare/normalize, but **three**.

Comment: The problem with what you're proposing is that the Sound is actually desyncing from the global timegame, even with getTimer, since a really little lag can make the sound play a little slower, thus it won't be sync with anything based on Time...

Comment: Okay, add `yourSoundChannel.position` into equation. This will return current position in milliseconds. Even there won't be a thing to convert, as all values are in milliseconds. If so, the actual procedure simplifies to check sound channel position against stored array of positions where you have to trigger your function.

Answer (score 2):

As I know sounds playing correlates with frames even if you add them dynamicaly. Try to use Event.ENTER_FRAME. If you know framerate (by default it's equal to 24 fps) and delay (X ms; when a "sync" note plays) then you can get a "sync" frame's index: index = fps * delay. Because for syncronization of a sound and frames  important only a nominal fps, not real. Count frames in the Event.ENTER_FRAME handler. When you will achieve the "sync" frame then you can execute your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just inform your mechanics code about what happens with music when you do render the music handling SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA? It should be pretty accurate, and you'll never be out of sync for more than one sound chunk (which is usually 2048-4096 float pairs as far as I remember, means 2048/44100 - 4096/44100 ~= 1/22 - 1/11 seconds). Also, I haven't checked this, but I believe, SAMPLE_DATA is fired right after the existing sound chunk started to play, so you can have the next one after it finishes ready, which would mean, if you write down the time of sound render start, then the actual sound will be played the exact that time later(if your system isn't overloaded), so you can calculate it very precisely, down to milliseconds.

Comment: I've try that, but the problem is if I add code when I play the "tick" sound, it's actually played after, on a delay depending on the flash player version... So it's not really sure.

Comment: It's normal it is played after, and it will be so not only on flash but on every platform and in every language(on PC), since sound output id buffered. So while you play one chunk, you need to get the next one ready, so it can be played without pause. Talking about your problem, as I said, the delay is probably constant and depends on size of chunk. However, if it really depends on fp version, I'd recommend to measure it for different versions, or use reading data from sound together with generating it to determine the delay in real time. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enapsulate that WAV generated music within a FLV stream (using only audio tags). Between the FLV audio tags insert FLV metadata tags, which you will [receive through onMetaData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000180.html) just when that portion is playing. Since you are generating music on the fly, you might wanna use NetStream.appendBytes() instead of just passing WAV files to NetStream.

You need to familiarize yourself with how FLV works, how appendBytes works and how to create a FLV (which you write into appendBytes() as if you are writing it to a file) which contains WAV audio.